# Have 5,000 mp3 songs need private space with beautiful player with huge options

Tags: streaming

I have 5,000 mp3 songs need private space with beautiful player with huge options

example, in local windows pc i have installed several softwares like winamp etc., also open source music library for quick navigation and play which has equalizers and everything.

Assume i may go out of station and left with a mobile or any pc with internet which won't have these softwares or features.

I am looking for a way to play music online with all the features.

Does any web-site has these features which provides private space with lesser cost?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about recommendations for where to buy etc are off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot recommend Google Play enough.  The ability to sync up to 20,000 tunes on to the service for free and access them as long as you have an internet connection.

The interface is nice and I even throw them the $10.00/mo so that I can continuously add new music for just that insanely low price (now I can buy more band t-shirts).  I went from 3k songs to almost 16k songs in just the 3 short years I've had this service.  The library is easy to search and looks pretty nice.